# Python: how to form the correct list

Tags: python, arrays, list, replace, trim

This is my data looks like

`my_list = [('Australia',), ('Europe',)]`

I need to remove the comma "," after every element.

`new_list = ['Australia', 'Europe']`

I can achieve this using a loop and extracting one element at a time and replacing it. Is there a better way to achieve the same. Thank you

Comment: So you have a list of tuples and this coma indicates it. You have 2 options: 1) x = [ x[0] for x in my_list ] or 2) x = [ list[x] for x in my_list ]  . In first you change tuple to single value, in second you convert tuple tu list.

Answer (score 0):

That comma, indicates that you have a tuple. If you want to not have that comma, you can change tuples to lists:

```py
new_list = [list(country) for country in my_list]
```

It gives You:

```
[['Australia'], ['Europe']]
```

Comment: how can I have just one bracket ['Australia', 'Europe']

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [('Australia',), ('Europe',)]
# lambda create a function and returns first value of x
# function map takes a function and list
# it puts every value of list to function 

country = list(map(lambda x: x[0], my_list))

print(country)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: sorry I'm new here. I will remember that

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that every element in `my_list` is a 1-element tuple:

```py
new_list = [inner_tuple[0] for inner_tuple in my_list]
```

If the number of elements in the inner tuple is not always 1, we can use the `itertools` library to "flatten" `my_list`:

```py
import itertools

new_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_list))
```

Reference: See the `flatten` function in the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) documentaton.